# Atlassian slug generatorGenerator

Tags: bitbucket, slug, bitbucket-server

Does Atlassian slug generation algorithm or any of its implementation public?

I need to check if repository name typed by user will have certain slug.

I found a lot of different algorithms, but I need to be sure that that's one used by Stash, where it's written that slug generation is done by BitBucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find it anywhere, but I suppose it looks like this:

Name cannot have other chars than letters, digits, whitespaces, hyphens, underscores and periods! Also its first char needs to be a letter or digit.

As a whitespace block I mean text found by regex: `[\s]+`.

1. Every whitespace block replace with simple hyphen.

   `My \t Exaple          Text.` -> `My-Example-Text.`
2. Lowercase all letters in string.

   `My-Example-Text.` -> `my-example-text.`